# Add elements of a list to a Slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to add the elements of a List to one slide. My code looks like this:

```
Sub Inhaltsverzeichnis_generator()
Set titels = New Dictionary
Set slideNr = New Collection
Dim sld As Slide
Dim inhaltsverzeichnis_Slide As Slide
Dim inhaltsverzeichnis_Shape_Titel As Shape
Dim inhaltsverzeichnis_Shape_Text As Shape  
Set inhaltsverzeichnis_Slide = Application.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutText)

Set inhaltsverzeichnis_Shape_Titel = inhaltsverzeichnis_Slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 30, 30, 650, 140)
With inhaltsverzeichnis_Shape_Titel.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.Size = 35
    .Text = "Introduction"
    .Lines.ParagraphFormat.SpaceWithin = 1.5
End With

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    If sld.Shapes.HasTitle Then
         'Debug.Print sld.SlideIndex & ": " & sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange
        titels.Add (sld.Shapes.title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
        slideNr.Add (sld.SlideIndex)
    End If
Next
Set inhaltsverzeichnis_Shape_Text = inhaltsverzeichnis_Slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 30, 110, 650, 140)
For Each title In titels
    With inhaltsverzeichnis_Shape_Text.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 10
        .Text = vbNewLine & title
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

My problem is that only the last element of the List will be displayed. it seems like other elements are overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem:

```
.Text = vbNewLine & title
```

Each time through the loop, you're setting .Text to the current value of title, not appending the current value of title to the existing text.

Change it to

```
.Text = .Text & vbNewLine & title
```